# Getting image from gallery in to alrt dialog

Tags: android

There are many tutorials on getting image from gallery which will work with activity, but how to get 
 image from gallery in to alert dialog,can any one help with a example

Comment: Create a custom dialog, put an image view inside of the xml, use the gallery intent, get the image path/bitmap, assign the image to the image view using this to initialize the image view `ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mImageView1);`

Comment: i want to get it without using startActivityForResult() method,becausing i am not using a alert dialog in prefence screen not activity

Comment: so you want user to choose an image from his local storage/gallery without using `startActivityForResult`?